# How to automatically fit data with several normal cumulative distribution functions in R

Tags: r

I have several data sets (hundreds of them actually), that I know can be fitted with the sum of several normal cumulative distributions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)).

Here is one example of such data set, here with two cumulative distribution functions:

```
library(pracma)
library(minpack.lm)

x <- seq(1, 1000, length.out = 50)
k1 <- 0.5
mu1 <- 500
sigma1 <- 100
y1 <- k1 * (1 + erf((x - mu1) / (sqrt(2) * sigma1)))

k2 <- 0.5
mu2 <- 300
sigma2 <- 50
y2 <- k2 * (1 + erf((x - mu2) / (sqrt(2) * sigma2)))

my.df <- data.frame(x, y = y1 + y2, type = "data")

ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

Now I want to fit those curves, so I use `nls` to do so:

```
model <- nlsLM(y ~ k1 * (1 + erf((x - mu1) / (sqrt(2) * sigma1)))
      + k2 * (1 + erf((x - mu2) / (sqrt(2) * sigma2))),
      start= c(mu1 = 500 , sigma1 = 50, k1 = 0.5,
               mu2 = 300 , sigma2 = 50, k2 = 0.5),
      data = my.df,
      control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500))

tmp <- data.frame(x, y = predict(model), type = "fit")

combined <- rbind(my.df, tmp)

ggplot(combined, aes(x, y, colour = type, shape = type)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Here is what I get:

[image: That's a good fit!]

The fit is great. However, I helped `nls` a lot:

- I gave it a perfect fitting curve as input, not raw data
- I told it my curve was the sum of two functions (not one or three)
- And I almost gave the solution by providing very close parameter values

To fix the first point, I compute 3 models for one, two and three functions and choose the one with the minimum deviance.

For the second point, with my hundreds of data sets unfortunately, the parameters change quite a bit and I have disappointing results when I give the same starting parameters for all sets.

Is there a better way to select those starting values?

I heard of the `mixtools` library, but I'm not sure it works for CDF (cumulative distribution functions).